# couldn't switch to requested monitor resolution in Windows 7

Tags: unity, directx, directx11, resolution

Run the game,and it shows that it couldn't switch to requested monitor resolution, DX11 could not switch resolution in Windows 7(both 32 and 64 bit ) when I tried to build the game with Unity 2017.3, and also on 2018.4, but the dialog keep popping out. I already tried to lowered the resolution and updated the integrated graphic driver, but nothing worked. Any idea would be appreicated.[image][image]

Comment: What resolution are you trying to set it to, and how does it compare against the set of supported display resolutions reported by [Screen.resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-resolutions.html)? How have you [configured your game's resolution/aspect ratios in your project settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html#Resolution)? (Or [for Universal Windows Platform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Resolution), if you're using that)

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for reply~I attached the photo on top

Comment: That answers only one of the three questions I asked you.

Comment: The monitor shows the dialog on the top support the resolution 1280x720, and the issue not only happened in this resolution, also 1280x740 or 1920x1080. If more information needed, please let me know, thank you

Comment: You still haven't told us your display's supported resolutions. What model is it? And what graphics card are you running on?

Comment: The display's supported resolution vary from 1920x1080, 1280x1024, 1280x720, and so on. Some of models are asus vb171 and asus VW192. All of the graphic card is integrated,Intel media accelarator,intel g45/g43 express chipset......

Answer (score 1):

Quick UPDATE

We solved the problem by getting the old version of Unity 5.6, and use dirextx 9 since our program for some reason have to be compatible with Windows 7 32 bit and even some oudated Windows XP. We still do not know about how the issue happened when we used newer vesrsion.